# Why is Python seemingly ignoring wildcards when extracting from a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, series

I'm currently doing some data cleanup, and I'm handling a Pandas DataFrame with columns that contain numbers and strings. Some rows have a value like 012345 and others have a value what seems like Excel formatting to text (e.g. ="012345")

So consider this example series:

```
raw_series = pd.Series([114254, 958554, '="142142"', '="987654"', 112233])
```

After running the following snippet:

```
re_numbers = re.compile(r"([0-9]*)")
num_series = raw_series.str.extract(re_numbers)
```

This is the expected result:
`([114254, 958554, 142142, 987654, 112233])`

This is the actual result: `([114254, 958554, , , 112233])`

After changing the regex pattern to this: `([0-9]{6})`

I achieve the expected result. The same outcome happens when using a negated set to extract numbers (e.g. `([^="]*)`) So what is happening here?

Comment: `="142142"` or `"=142142"`?

Comment: The former @HenryYik

Comment: The Series contains 3 integers and 2 strings?

Comment: @AMC That would be correct.

Comment: When I do leave them as numbers, the regex works only on the strings. Is all the data a 6 digit numbers with or without an equals sign in front?

Comment: I edited the example series, perhaps that should make it a little more clear as to what kind of data I'm working with. I simply added single quotes around the strings in the series.

Comment: Wait, so they're strings which contain quotes? I'm guessing you only care about getting the numbers out of the strings?

Comment: It might be worth editing your post to clarify things, as it stands saying _I'm handling a Pandas DataFrame with columns that contain numbers_ followed by _Some rows have a value like "012345"_ is contradictory.

Comment: That would be correct, some values are strings containing quotes. Regardless if it contains quotes or not, I would like to extract the numbers out of the series.

Edit: Noted, will make the appropriate changes, thanks

Comment: Alright, can you tell us more about the data? Are all the strings following a same format? Do you have an actual example from the data?

Comment: @AMC In the series all values that are strings follow that same format as described in the example, and what I gave as an example is an actual sample out of the data. How can I give a better example if that would help?

Comment: As long as they all follow the format you already described, everything is fine!

Comment: It's single quotes on the outside, double quotes on the inside in your data, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
>>> raw_series = pd.Series([114254, 958554, '="142142"', '="987654"', 112233])                                          
>>> raw_series.astype('str').str.extract(r"([0-9]+)")
        0
0  114254
1  958554
2  142142
3  987654
4  112233
```

---

Why does this (and your own solution) work?

Because `*` matches anything, including zero matches. Regular expression matches are greedy, so it will absorb all numbers as a single match, but if the first character is not a number, then the *first* match will be the empty match. If you had used `extractall`, you'd find the relevant string in later matches(*).

My solution simply demands at least one number, so the empty string will not match.

(*) Like this:

```
>>> raw_series.astype('str').str.extractall(r"([0-9]*)")
              0                                                                                                         
  match
0 0      114254
  1         NaN
1 0      958554
  1         NaN
2 0         NaN
  1         NaN
  2      142142
  3         NaN
  4         NaN
3 0         NaN
  1         NaN
  2      987654
  3         NaN
  4         NaN
4 0      112233
  1         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

@0 0 beat me to it, but yes, it's because you're using the `*` token, which matches **zero** or more times.

A simple tweak to your current regex fixes everything:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

re_numbers = re.compile(r"([0-9]+)")

raw_series = pd.Series([114254, 958554, '="142142"', '="987654"', 112233])

match_series = raw_series.str.extract(re_numbers, expand=False)

res_series = raw_series.copy()
res_series[match_series.notna()] = match_series
res_series = res_series.astype(int)

print(f"match_series:\n{match_series}\n")
print(f"res_series:\n{res_series}")
```

Output:

```
match_series:
0       NaN
1       NaN
2    142142
3    987654
4       NaN
dtype: object

res_series:
0    114254
1    958554
2    142142
3    987654
4    112233
dtype: int64
```

---

It can, and probably should, be further improved using the information we have on the data's format. The complete pattern looks like this: `=\"(\d{6})\"`.

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

re_numbers = re.compile(r"=\"(\d{6})\"")

raw_series = pd.Series([114254, 958554, '="142142"', '="987654"', 112233])

match_series = raw_series.str.extract(re_numbers, expand=False)

res_series = raw_series.copy()
res_series[match_series.notna()] = match_series
res_series = res_series.astype(int)

print(f"match_series:\n{match_series}\n")
print(f"res_series:\n{res_series}")
```

Output:

```
match_series:
0       NaN
1       NaN
2    142142
3    987654
4       NaN
dtype: object

res_series:
0    114254
1    958554
2    142142
3    987654
4    112233
dtype: int64
```